# How to send original users password to his mail (before bcryption)

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, bcrypt, observers

In my system users can't register. Admin adding all users in the admin panel and telling them your password is "xxx". Right now i need to send mail to users. Which contains users email and users password. System is working great. But there is one exception. In the mail, passwords is bcrypted. How can i solve? I don't any clue. I am using **observers**. In the model:

```
    public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    self::created(function () {
        $customer = Customer::latest()->get()->first();
        Mail::send('emails.user_login_informations', ['customer' => $customer], function($message) use($customer) {
            $message->to($customer->email, $customer->name, $customer->password)
                ->subject('Login Information');
        });
    });
}
```

ps: this is working. In my mail:

```
Your email: xxx@example.com 
Your Password: $2y$10$/GW5XNH9KGU.Nz05PZHFJuKb2ldhwYhS8oMX9e7HJIuFNJ
```

But this looks like:

```
Your email: xxx@example.com 
Your Password: 123
```

Comment: hashing is supposed to hide the password from everyone, so instead of sending the password back to user usually a token is send to create new password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a temporary password field and delete it upon user activation. I needed this for a real world example. For instance:

```
Event::listen('rainlab.user.activate', function($user) {
    $user->temp_password = null;
    $user->save();
});

User::saving(function ($user) {
    $password = post('User.password');
    if ($password && ! $user->attributes['is_activated']) {
        $user->temp_password = $password;
    }
});
```

As mentioned above though, this includes a big security risk.

Comment: I made it different way. But similar to yours. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You hash user passwords to increase the security. The Hashing functionality is a one way hashing, so it can't be reversed.

A better way would be to create a password reset token und send it to the user. So the user can set a new password with the email address / token combination. To increase this method you could let the token expire after 30 minutes or so.

Comment: yes you are absolutly right. But what i meant is: can we do this? Is it possible with **creating** method in observer or something else. If its not possible, sure, i am chaning my codes.

Comment: It is only possible when you save the plain password when a new user registers or changes his password. The hashing algorithm is a one way algorithm like I said for security reasons.